# Difference:Too Vs Very

Tags: adjectives, modifiers, intensifiers

Grammar often says that *very* is used with the affirmative form of the adjective; since *very* is to denote positive connotation. But the following sentence seems to me the paradox of the above rule:

> Why fellows like that are too young at fifty?

Comment: It would really, really help if you told us where that sentence came from, and let us see some of the surrounding context. I hope you'll read [**this meta post**](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source) and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: The cited 'rule' relates to the word *very*, but *very* doesn't appear in your example. As such, that rule is irrelevant in that context. You might want to look up the usage of *too* instead.

Comment: @Lawrence the rule is cited because the question author thought that ,considering the rule, 'very' should be used in this context, but it isn't. I agree with you that the definition of 'too' is important, but if he thinks 'very' should be used in this context then its definition isn't irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

## Very

**[Definition:](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/very?s=t)**

> in a high degree; extremely; exceedingly:
>   *A giant is very tall.*

**Example:**

> That car is **very** fast.

This means the car is more than just fast, faster than a fast car.

## Too:

**[Definition:](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/too?s=t)**

> to an excessive extent or degree; beyond what is desirable, fitting,
>   or right:

**Example:**

> That car is **too** fast.

The car is so fast, it's not good anymore. You want it to be slower.

## Your sentence:

If that sentence is from the book ['Goodbye Mr Chips'](https://books.google.be/books?id=usSgCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT30&lpg=PT30&dq=Why%20fellows%20like%20that%20are%20too%20young%20at%20fifty&source=bl&ots=XmpuF_Dfmo&sig=w_BGoUbZvouunanzveYWY6sRq28&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjByMbKw9bVAhWBmLQKHeeLAP8Q6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=Why%20fellows%20like%20that%20are%20too%20young%20at%20fifty&f=false), the entire sentence is:

> Too old at fifty - why, fellows like that are too *young* at fifty.

The context is here very important. He doesn't think you're '**too** old' at fifty and that's why he says '**too** young'. It's just repeating the same word as before, where too is used like explained above.